# iOS - How to limit the MapView to a specific region?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, android-mapview, region

I have the following problem:

I have a "drawn map" (image) which I add to the MapView as an Overlay. No Problem with that.. but I need to limit the MapView to the region of the Overlay, so a user isn't able to scroll/zoom outside of this region.. but it should be possible to scroll/zoom inside the "bounds" of the overlay - means I cannot just disable zoom/scrolling for the MapView.

Are there any ideas/solution on this topic? The reason for using the MapView/-Kit is that I need to add various POIs to the custom map. This may become more complex when just using an ImageView+ScrollView for presenting the custom map.

I've researched alot on this topic, but I didn't found a nice solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Best Regards,
Christian

**Edit: This is our solution:**
*You supply a topleft and a bottomright coordinate to limit the map. The (minimum) zoomlevel is also limited. I've deactivated decelerating and you are able to bounce a bit out of the map (for better performance/ux). I added a ~1km grey border to the overlay so the user isnÄt able to see the orignal worldmap of google.*

**LimitedMapView.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface LimitedMapView : MKMapView <UIScrollViewDelegate>{

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoordinate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoordinate;


@end
```

**LimitedMapView.m:**

```
#import "LimitedMapView.h"

@implementation LimitedMapView

@synthesize topLeftCoordinate, bottomRightCoordinate;

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    if([super respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidZoom:)]) [super scrollViewDidZoom:scrollView];

    if ([self region].span.latitudeDelta > 0.002401f || [self region].span.longitudeDelta > 0.003433f) {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D center = self.centerCoordinate;
        MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.002401f, 0.003433f);

        self.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);

    }

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

    if([super respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidEndDragging:)]) [super scrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView willDecelerate:decelerate];

    MKCoordinateRegion currentRegion = self.region;
    bool changeRegionLong = YES;
    bool changeRegionLat = YES;

    // LONGITUDE    
    if((currentRegion.center.longitude - (currentRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2)) < self.topLeftCoordinate.longitude) {

        currentRegion.center.longitude = (topLeftCoordinate.longitude + (currentRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2));

    } else if((currentRegion.center.longitude + (currentRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2)) > self.bottomRightCoordinate.longitude) {

        currentRegion.center.longitude = (bottomRightCoordinate.longitude - (currentRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2));

    } else {

        changeRegionLong = NO;

    }

    // LATITUDE    
    if((currentRegion.center.latitude + (currentRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2)) > self.topLeftCoordinate.latitude) {

        currentRegion.center.latitude = (topLeftCoordinate.latitude - (currentRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2));

    } else if((currentRegion.center.latitude - (currentRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2)) < self.bottomRightCoordinate.latitude) {

        currentRegion.center.latitude = (bottomRightCoordinate.latitude + (currentRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2));

    } else {

        changeRegionLat = NO;

    }

    if(changeRegionLong || changeRegionLat) [self setRegion:currentRegion animated:YES];

}

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for updating with solution.  I just wanted to limit max zoom, and ran into a bit of a problem w/ using just scrollViewDidZoom:  To anyone else out there, make sure you set your new span to LESS than the if check span otherwise the mapview will get stuck at max zoom.

Comment: A better written solution for swift is there http://stackoverflow.com/a/31799617/2814964

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By implementing :

`-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

You should be able to reset region to your specific one.

Look [at that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440778/how-to-follow-user-location-with-mapkit/3614491#3614491) to have an example of how to do this.

---

Another solution, that brings *more precise events but is **more complex*** *(I'm currently using this successfully for another need)* is to subclass `MKMapView` and override `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol.

If you do that, make sure to call `super` implementation like that  :

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewWillBeginDragging:)])
    [super scrollViewWillBeginDragging:scrollView];
  // do what you want
}
```

*Note: While the protocol is public, `MKMapView` implementation is unknown and might differ with iOS versions, so it is more safe to check with `respondsToSelector:` before. You **must** call super implementations or Map will just not work properly*.

Comment: Hmm.. I think this delegate will fire when I start moving the Map. Unfortunalety at this moment I don't know what the user will do with the Map (could be a valid zoom/scroll gesture). And the `-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated` fires too late. Or am I totally wrong with this?!

Comment: added another solution that might help ;)

Comment: that's not so nice, just dirty "hacking" a bit some apis that are not open enough for certain uses... aah if *only apple* and google were still *friends* we might have a featured and stable `MapKit`...

Comment: in this case, anything which will work and look ok (for the end-user), is a nice solution to me. but you're right... there definitely should be a method included to limit the viewable region :/

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Added my solution to the question. For the moment it's ok for us :).

Answer (score 14):

After trying different ways of limited MKMapView I've concluded that using mapDidChange, and resetting if you're center point goes outside of the boundaries works best, with animated: YES

Here's how I do it (Using the New Zealand lat/Long span/center).

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{ 
  if ((mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta > 15.589921 ) || (mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta > 175.836914) ) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-41.162114, 172.836914);

    MKCoordinateSpan spanOfNZ = MKCoordinateSpanMake(13.589921, 14.062500 );

    MKCoordinateRegion NZRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoord, spanOfNZ);

    [mapView setRegion: NZRegion animated: YES];
  }

 if (abs(abs(mapView.region.center.latitude) - 41.162114) > (13.589921 / 2) ) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-41.162114, 172.836914);

    MKCoordinateSpan spanOfNZ = MKCoordinateSpanMake(13.589921, 14.062500 );

    MKCoordinateRegion NZRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoord, spanOfNZ);

    [mapView setRegion: NZRegion animated: YES];

  }

  if (abs(abs(mapView.region.center.longitude) - 172.836914) > (14.062500 / 2) ) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-41.162114, 172.836914);

     MKCoordinateSpan  spanOfNZ = MKCoordinateSpanMake(13.589921, 14.062500 );

     MKCoordinateRegion NZRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoord, spanOfNZ);

     [mapView setRegion: NZRegion animated: YES];
  }
}
```

Comment: I should mention the above code also has a limit on the zoom level.

Comment: For anyone else trying to get this to work, this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: This turned into an infinite recursion to me. I had to unset the map delegate from the NIB, and set the delegate in `viewDidLoad` after setting the initial region.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Small note - If anyone else has trouble with this in future I had to change abs(x) to fabs(x) as lon/lats are doubles and abs(x) returns an int. This doesn't seem to matter with the values you have as they are so large, but I was working with much smaller regions!

Comment: This crashes my app. And how did you get this value (mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta > 15.589921 )?? 15.589921?? And should mapView be self.mapView?

Comment: While this has definitely worked for me (and you have received my upvote) it is overly verbose and there is one too many absolute value function. (Do use fabs(x) as @bean pointed out).  I've created a more legible gist for anyone interested: https://gist.github.com/Alp-Phone/e11cca67e77285566d4d

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question, but to avoid the infinite loop you could try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126011/1234011

Basically set a flag to prevent the callback from firing again if it was you who set the value.

- Ken