# callout bubble MKMapView move problem

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Im currently developping an App which uses a MKMapView. Wenn the map is moved I perform server request to get new Annotations based on the coordinates.

Wenn an annotation is clicked it sometines moves the map. In this case i don't want to perform a Request.

Has somebody a solution how to know if it was an callout buble which moved the map ?

I tried with - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{ without success !

Comment: Are you doing the server request from regionWillChangeAnimated or regionDidChangeAnimated?  What did you try in didSelectAnnotationView?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680896/ios-how-to-limit-the-mapview-to-a-specific-region/5681488#5681488) where I explain several methods to track that the MKMapView has moved.

That answers a different problem, but I think that might help you.