# Limit the MapView to a certain area but still able to zoom in and out

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, mapkit

Is it possible that I limit `MKMapView` to a certain area but I can still zoom in and out on that area?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

        var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.055, 0.055)
        var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 7.466988, longitude: 134.562119), span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean limit? you are setting the region and that will work for you

Comment: Limit the MKMapView to that area or city. i.e. I can only view USA and if I try to drag/slide the map to Canada I won't be able to.

Comment: Hope you can find you answer here: [iOS - How to limit the MapView to a specific region?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680896/ios-how-to-limit-the-mapview-to-a-specific-region). Good luck!