# How to set boundaries on Map in MapKit IOS8 and Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, mapkit

After a lot of research on this useful website, i put the guns down...

I have a map with a lot of annotations.
I will set boundaries in order to users stays on the wanted place.
All documentations I've found were for Objective C and previous ios.

I'm looking for a way to do it for IOS 8 and Swift pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't check it but logically the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147386/1836536) will work for you.you can reset the region between the desired Geo Coordinates by calculating it exceed the boundaries.am no good with swift but you can try bellow code

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

    if ((mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta > 15.589921 ) || (mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta > 175.836914) ) {

        var centerCoord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-41.162114, 172.836914);
        var spanOfNZ:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(13.589921, 14.062500);
        var NZRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoord, spanOfNZ);
        mapView .setRegion(NZRegion, animated: true);

    }
}
```

Comment: thx, i ve already found this topic, but my problem is to find a Swift code instead of objective c code