# Allow user to zoom in but not out on mapview region - iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

When my mapView is loaded, I set the mapRegion to the following:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 700, 700);
[self.mapView setRegion:region];
```

I want the user to be able to zoom in on the region, but not zoom out past it.

What is the best way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MKMapViews are a bit limited but this solution might help you out.

[iOS - How to limit the MapView to a specific region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680896/ios-how-to-limit-the-mapview-to-a-specific-region)