# Get US only map for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, mapkit, mapbox

I want to draw the map of United States with all its states and state boundaries, Please help
Just like the image below
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - How to limit the MapView to a specific region?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680896/ios-how-to-limit-the-mapview-to-a-specific-region)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SVG file parsing for it

FSInteractiveMap is a charting library to visualize and interact with a vector map on iOS. It's like Geochart but for iOS!

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fsinteractivemap

Comment: @HrishikeshMenon Thanks