# Limit region of Google maps seen by a user based on their Address?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API and have a couple of questions. I want to make it so that my current user can only see 10 miles from their home address in each direction.

I already have the users home address being displayed. I just need to know how to make it so that it only shows a limited region of 10 miles in the map.

This is how I show the user's home address:

```
func getCurrentUsersHomeAddress() {
        let userID = currentUser?.uid
        ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let username = snapshot.value!["fullName"] as! String
            let homeAddress = snapshot.value!["homeAddress"] as! [Double]
            let email = snapshot.value!["email"] as! String
            let lat = homeAddress[0] as Double
            let long = homeAddress[1] as Double
            let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat as CLLocationDegrees, longitude: long as CLLocationDegrees)
            self.mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: coords, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
            let marker = GMSMarker(position: coords)
```

Remember, I just want to show 10 miles of the map. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680896/ios-how-to-limit-the-mapview-to-a-specific-region) has answers you might be looking for. However, most of them are using overlays to restrict it. Hope this helps!

Comment: I need an answer in swift

Comment: Sorry about that. Still, it looks like there's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680896/ios-how-to-limit-the-mapview-to-a-specific-region) about your inquiry